# Boost (.asio) linking

Tags: boost, boost-asio

So I followed [this](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef), all the way to the "Include Boost headers and link with Boost libraries" section.

For asio, what do I #include (besides asio.hpp, of course)and what libraries do I link?

In fact, is there a big list somewhere of all the boost libraries, and what you need to include to get them to work?
That would be very useful.

Comment: Is there a specific compilation or linking error you are receiving in a specific environment?

Answer (score 0):

I am talking by heart.but.for using boost.asio in windows I remember you needed to define WINNT 0X501 or similar and link against boost.system and the win32 sockets library.

Comment: I get: `'DWORD_PTR_' does not name a type`  whan I #include system.hpp. Presumably this is because it relies on something else that I haven't included?

Comment: For me it worked without having to include any of those. But now I don't have access to the setup I did, sorry. It looks as if you didn't provide the required define for Windows. Take a look at the docs.

Comment: I tried what you said, then _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 at the behest of a compiler error.